# How to add WYSIWYG Editor in Magento system configuration?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, wysiwyg, system-configuration

I want to add WYSIWYG editor in Magento system configuration.

And also get the value from the that is there option to do this.

Cheers.

Comment: You can use [This](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/how-to-add-wysiwyg-functionality-to-magento-config-items) link to add wysiwyg editor in your configuration fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the answer from this [**post**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/how-to-add-wysiwyg-functionality-to-magento-config-items). Thanks to [**Marius**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius) for giving this answer.

First of all add this in any layout file, to load the editor in the config section:

```
<adminhtml_system_config_edit>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setCanLoadTinyMce"><load>1</load></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_system_config_edit>
```

Now create your own field renderer. It has to be a block inside your module:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Editor extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field implements Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface{
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element){
        $element->setWysiwyg(true);
        $element->setConfig(Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig());
        return parent::_getElementHtml($element);
    }
}
```

Now for the element inside the system.xml set the frontend_type 'editor' and the frontend_model your new block

```
<fieldname translate="label">
    <label>Field label </label>
    <frontend_type>editor</frontend_type>
    <frontend_model>module/adminhtml_system_config_editor</frontend_model>
    <sort_order>150</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</fieldname>
```

There are some issues when changing the config scope to a website or a store view. The textarea does not become 'disabled'. But if you can ignore this, you can use it without any problems.

Comment: Good description, but very short for a magento beginners like me. Download this sample and edit it as Meenakshi said for 100% working solution: http://www.junaidbhura.com/add-color-picker-magento-admin-anywhere/

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is add a WYSIWYG editor with its appropriate adminhtml controller. After this, you can load the editor for every configfield you specify.

Try reading [this article](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/add-wysiwyg-editor-in-magento-custom-module). It is a step-by-step guide how to add the editor.

Comment: a link is not an answer: please edit your answer to describe what are the necessary steps, leave the link for reference

Comment: @richardbernards  above link reference is for add WYSIWYG editor in admin form.I want to add in system configuration

Comment: The system configuration is one big admin form ;)

Comment: @RichardBernards i get WYSIWYG editor bt there is css problem. i cant see perfact structure. what to do for that?